# StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow. While adding object to list

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, exception, stack-overflow

I've writen void that returns `List<>` of objects. But it crashes with:

> StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack
> overflow. System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T].set_Capacity
> (System.Int32 value) (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T].EnsureCapacity (System.Int32 min)
> (at <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)
> System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T].AddWithResize (T item) (at
> <6073cf49ed704e958b8a66d540dea948>:0)

Here is my code:

```
public List<Object> MyObjects;

public List<Object> AllObjectsExcluding(string excludedObjectId)
    {
        List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();

        foreach (Object object in MyObjects)
        {
            if (object.id != excludedObjectId)
            {
                objects.Add(object); //StackOverflowException
            }
        }

        return objects;
    }

public class Object
    {
        public string id;
    }
```

Comment: Resizing a `List` cannot normally cause a stack overflow (it only allocates heap memory). Check for an infinite recursive loop in the rest of your code (the full stack trace should be a hint there) as well as any other stack allocations that might not leave enough room for the call stack. Some kind of stack pointer corruption due to intermediate, incorrect unmanaged calls unbalancing the stack is a more remote possibility.

Comment: My guess is that the example function is called by some recursive function. I.e. check the call stack for any repeated function, or sequence of repeated functions.

Comment: Calling a class  Object could also lead to issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in general **do not use `Object` as name for your own type!**

It is already confusing enough having both [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object), the implicit mother type of everything in `c#` and [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html), the mother type of all asset like references in Unity.

---

Further there is a type alias `object` (== `System.Object`)

=> The code you show us here wouldn't even compile at all as `object` (and any other built-in [keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/) and [type alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types)) is not allowed as variable names.

---

Finally, as mentioned in the comments, the code you show us (besides before mentioned compiling issues) wouldn't produce that exception => It has to be something else you haven't shown us.

---

For your use case you would be better simply using [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)

```
using System.Linq;

...


return MyObjects.Where(obj => obj.id != excludedObjectId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case example function was also called by some recursive function. Thanks JonasH!